# Using object paradigm on atomic integer value, for display purpose : right or wrong?

Tags: php, object, integer

I am working on financial values for poker games. All amounts are internally given as cents. Therefore, the type is integer. But, I need to display the amounts in several ways. So far, I work like this (PHP) :

```
class Amount
{
    private value;

    public function set($v) ...
    public function get() ...
    public function add($v) ... // $v is integer
    ...
    public function displayLikeThis() ...
    public function displayLikeThat() ...
}
$value1 = new Amount(100);
$value2 = new Amount(200);
// ...
// Working with value1 and value2
// ...
// Then need to do value1 += value2 : 
$value1->add( $value2->get() );
/*
Note : 
I can also check parameter type in
the add method. Then, the previous line could be :
$value1->add( $value2 );
*/
echo $value1->displayLikeThis();
```

It works like a charm, but since PHP is not able to overload operators, my code is quite "heavy" and I am wondering if I am doing it the wrong way. Finally, is it still "object paradigm" to work like this :

```
$value1 = 100;
$value2 = 200;
$val = new Amount($value1 + $value2);
echo $val->display1();
```

The code is liter when doing operations, but I feel wrong creating a new Amount object each time I just want to display a value (and in this case the class name would be AmountDisplayer).

My question : what is the correct **POO way** to work with integer values ?

Thanks

Comment: If it encapsulates some form of curreny, yes absolutely.

Comment: *(related)* http://martinfowler.com/ap2/quantity.html

Answer (score 0):

If domain method *add* is part of your *domain*, yes, this is the right way to do. If not, in my option `$value1->add($value2)` is unnecessary.

Comment: Funny that you question `add` but not the `display*` methods. IMHO, these are much more likely candidates for removal because those probably belong on the presentation layer.

Comment: @Gordon yes, I focused on the domain methods. As you said, `display*` belongs of presentation layer in fact but I understood that it's not the "main" problem... or not, anyway...

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. In fact, I did not name correctly my method. Instead of displayLikeThis(), you should read getThisKindOfFormat() and getThatKindOfFormat(). Example : I have a value of 1000, and one of the method could return something like "1K", another one "1 000,00", and so on. This result might be displayed, or used in some other way (stored in a file). I do not understand what you mean when you say "domain". Could you explain more ? Thank you again...